# Convert a Base64 LDIF file to plaintext (for import)

Tags: linux, ldap, base64, ldif

I have a LDIF file which has a multi-value Base64-encoded attribute, and I'd like to convert it in non-Base64-encoded syntax.  How can this be done?

**Context**

The LDIF file is as such:

```
dn: cn=johndoe,ou=clients,ou=management,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: foobarStatus
foobarStatus:: ZW5hYmxl... (Base64 string) ...ZCA9IHRydWU
```

where the decoded Base64 string is as such:

```
market = "US"
mgmt.account.mode = "X12"
foo.field = "Something"
bar.field = "Something else" 
...
```

**Problem**

When I try to import this LDIF file into a LDAP server via `ldapmodify`, I get an error:

```
ldapmodify: invalid format (line 4) entry: "cn=johndoe,ou=clients,ou=management,dc=example,dc=com"
```

I've been trying to solve this for a while but couldn't find the error. It could be some spurious character somewhere. Therefore I thought of converting the Base64 part of the LDIF and importing it on this format.  The attribute values  don't contain any non-printable ASCII (e.g. accented letters) so it should work fine.

**Note**

This could be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) so if anyone has another suggestion, I'm eager to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `ldapmodify` doesn't like long lines.  Therefore, after splitting the Base64 code here

```
foobarStatus:: ZW5hYmxl... (Base64 string) ...ZCA9IHRydWU
```

into multiple lines of 79 chars or less, `ldapmodify` was able to import it.

This solved my original problem.  I'm leaving the solution here for future readers.