# What is the appropriate syntax to separate multiple values in a LDAP multi-valued attribute?

Tags: ldap, format

This question is related to [Convert a Base64 LDIF file to plaintext (for import)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117733/convert-a-base64-ldif-file-to-plaintext-for-import) .

A LDAP I'm using has some attributes containing multiple values. E.g. `foobarStatus` has the following value:

```
market = "US"
mgmt.account.mode = "X12"
foo.field = "Something"
bar.field = "Something else"
```

(When this attribute is added or modified via a LDIF file, this value is imported encoded in Base64.)

Using Ldapadmin (a LDAP GUI client) to examine the entry shows the value of this attribute as such:

```
market = "US"mgmt.account.mode = "X12"foo.field = "Something"bar.field = "Something else"
```

which made me think about the question in the title: What is the appropriate syntax to separate multiple values in a LDAP multi-valued attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF I understand what you are trying to perform.

You do not use a separator to implement multiple values within LDAP/LDIF.
Each attribute is a container for value(s).

So IF I understand what you are trying to perform a LDIF something like this should work:

```
dn: cn=johndoe,ou=clients,ou=management,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
delete: foobarStatus
-
add:foobarStatus
foobarStatus: market = "US"
foobarStatus: mgmt.account.mode = "X12"
foobarStatus: foo.field = "Something"
foobarStatus: bar.field = "Something else"
```

Also keep in mind:

- there are some characters that either need escaped within LDIF operations
- there can NOT be any spaces at the end of a value

or the values will be base64 encoded.